# How to resolve all vector drawable warnings

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, svg, android-vectordrawable

Importing a vector asset from optimized SVG will cause bunch of warnings. we should use `0.123` instead of `.123`. some old devices may crash with the short syntax.

how ever there is no option to fix all warnings. fixing them one by one doesn't seems like a good idea!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was not obvious and took me some time to discover it, i decided to share my answer so it may help some one in future...

---

You can run code inspector, from there you can fix all warnings with just a click. open your infected xml. from the menu bar go to

- Analyze => Inspect code... => select `File ...\app\` => ok

proceed and wait for code inspector to find all issues. then right click on issues to resolve all problems.
 (You may need to run code inspector couple of times to get all warnings fixed.)

[image]